# Using onblur event for mutiple form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onblur

I have a simple function that applies formatting to a form field using an onblur event - if 7 characters have been input into the field, the field's border turns green.  Fewer than 7 character results in a red border.  I'd like to be able to apply the function to each form field individually as the user tabs through.  Currently, if I fill in the first form field, both form fields are formatted at the same time.  I think the answer is using a for loop that iterates through the inputs, I just don't know how to update my code to reflect that; any help is much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function charCount() {
var char = document.getElementById("numb").value.toString().length
if (char == 7) {
    $("input").addClass("green").removeClass("red");
} else {
 $("input").addClass("red").removeClass("green");
 }
}
</script>

<style>
.green {border-color:#009900;}
.red {border-color:#990000;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Please input ID numbers:</p>
<input id="numb" maxlength = 7 onblur="charCount()">
<input id="numb" maxlength = 7 onblur="charCount()">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- You **cannot** have the same **id** for multiple inputs. Use a class instead.

2.- Then use **"this"** to have a reference of the input that is being used
Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
 $(".numb").blur(function(){
        var char = $(this).val().length;
        if (char == 7) {
            $(this).addClass("green").removeClass("red");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("red").removeClass("green");
        }
    });
```

```css
.green {border-color:#009900;}
.red {border-color:#990000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Please input ID numbers:</p>
<input class="numb" maxlength = 7>
<input class="numb" maxlength = 7>
```

Comment: this is awesome, perfect. And yes, haha, a bit embarrassed that I broke rule #1.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

some points mate:

1. First thing, elements should not have same id in one html document. They can have same class but not ids.
2. `document.getElementById("numb").value.toString().length` you are trying to find the input from user using this statement. This will always pick the value from one particular item. Better use `$(this)` in the event handler(i suppose you are using jquery and know how to do it)
3. `$("input").addClass` using this.. you are targeting all the input elements present in the document. Be specific to what you want to target to.

Do it like this:
html:

```
<input class="numb" maxlength = 7 onblur="charCount()">
<input class="numb" maxlength = 7 onblur="charCount()">
```

JS:

```
$('.numb').on('blur', function() {
     // you access the current input elem with $(this)
     var inputElem = $(this);
     var char = inputElem.val().length;
     if (char == 7) {
         inputElem.addClass("green").removeClass("red");
     } else {
         inputElem.addClass("red").removeClass("green");
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh! Wow, can't believe i used the ID twice, even I know that's wrong. . . guess I was just looking at the code for too long.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code:

1) When you use this selector `$("input")`  You are applying the class to all inputs instead of a specific input.  You need to create a selector which targets the specific input which is blurred.

```
$("input").addClass("green").removeClass("red");
```

2) You are using same id for both input elements

```
<input id="numb" maxlength = 7 onblur="charCount()">
<input id="numb" maxlength = 7 onblur="charCount()">
```

3) You are mixing selectors of vanilla javascript and jQuery which can cause problems, it's better to use one or the other for your clarity.

VERSION:
This is the version with least changes to what you have already come up with, but the way you have attached the event is quite inefficient.

```
<script>
function charCount(num) {
var elem = $("#numb" + num);
var char = elem.value.toString().length;

if (char == 7) {
    $(elem).addClass("green").removeClass("red");
} else {
    $(elem).addClass("red").removeClass("green");
}
}
</script>

<style>
.green {border-color:#009900;}
.red {border-color:#990000;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Please input ID numbers:</p>
<input id="numb1" maxlength = 7 onblur="charCount(1)">
<input id="numb2" maxlength = 7 onblur="charCount(2)">
```

BETTER VERSION:

```
<html>
</head>
<script>
function init() {
  $('input').on('blur', function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      if(elem.val().length < 7) {
         elem.addClass('red').removeClass('green');
      }
      else {
         elem.removeClass('red').addClass('green');
      }
  });
}
$( document ).ready(init);
</script>
<style>
.green {border-color:#009900;}
.red {border-color:#990000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please input ID numbers:</p>
<input maxlength = 7>
<input maxlength = 7>
</body>
</html>
```

An event better solution would be to use IIFEs.

I would suggest you go through some resources for learning event handling:
    `https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/`
    `https://api.jquery.com/category/events/`
    `http://gregfranko.com/blog/jquery-best-practices/`

Hope it helps!